# Extract specific string by regular expression in Android

Tags: android, regex

I have this strings: https://regex101.com/r/7Er0Ch/6

I want put all my `http://esupb.tabriz.ir:808x/srvSC.svc` into array list.So in order to i used matcher like blow:

```
String regx= "#\\d+#";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
String[] metadata = new String[4];
while (matcher.find()) {
    metadata[0] = matcher.group(1);
    metadata[1] = matcher.group(2);
    metadata[2] = matcher.group(3);
    metadata[3] = matcher.group(4);
}
```

but I got not appropriate result. What is my mistake?

Comment: what does `Matcher#groupCount()` return?

Comment: It is `matcher.groupCount() =1` @pskink

Comment: so if you have one group what is `matcher.group(2)` used for? and 3 and 4?

Comment: It was for test ... Why i have one group?I should 10 group! right?@pskink

Comment: no, you define your groups in the pattern: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html

Comment: Now in group i have just #1# and like that but i want my string `http://test.ir:8080/srvSC.svc` what can i do?@pskink

Comment: maybe: `#\d+#(.*)#\d+#`? https://regex101.com/r/7Er0Ch/7

Comment: Yes.That's it.thnks @pskink

Comment: Is it possible to use for split, my url and put all `http://test.ir:8080/srvSC.svc` into list? how? @pskink

Comment: `"for split for"`?? meaning what?

Comment: Sory about my English my mean is ,put  all `http://test.ir:8080/srvSC.svc` into a list by matcher. is it posible?@pskink

Comment: you have `while (matcher.find()) {` so use it to find all the matches

Comment: Please write your answer to separate post because i want to check your answer .@pskink

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/7Er0Ch/7/codegen?language=java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From requirement your regex will be

> "(#\d+#)(http[^#]*svc)(#\d+#)"

```
group(0): (#\\d+#)(http[^#]*svc)(#\\d+#)
group(1): (#\\d+#)
group(2): (http[^#]*svc)
group(3): (#\\d+#)
```

Change your code to

```
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();

String url =
        "#1#http://test.com:8080/srv.svc#1# " +
                "#2#http://test.com:8081/srv.svc#2# " +
                "#3#http://test.com:8082/srv.svc#3# " +
                "#4#http://test.com:8083/srv.svc#4# " +
                "#5#http://test.com:8084/srv.svc#5# ";

String regx = "(#\\d+#)(http[^#]*svc)(#\\d+#)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

int from = 0;
while (matcher.find(from)) {
    urls.add(matcher.group(2));
    from = matcher.start() + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You regex `#\\d+#`matches `#` followed by matching one or more times a digit and then another `#` .It does not use [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

For your example data you could [remove that match](http://rextester.com/XURZFS78083) from the string giving you the desired result leaving out matching any pattern for the string that is left. It could also match inside the string instead of only at the start and the end.

To match your example string(s) like `http://esupb.tabriz.ir:808x/srvSC.svc` you might use your regex to match the start and the end, and capture in a group what is in between.

`^#\d+#(https?://test.ir:808\d/srvSC\.svc)#\d+#$`

In Java

`^#\\d+#(https?://test.ir:808\\d/srvSC\\.svc)#\\d+#$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/anEPhH/1)

[Demo Java](http://rextester.com/ESS90846)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `#\d+#` Match #, one or more times a digit and another #
- `(` Start capturing group

  - `https?://test.ir:808\d` Match the start of the url with an optional s `s?` and a digit after 808. Use `\d+` to match one or more digits.
  - `/srvSC\.svc` Match /srvSC.svc
  - `#\d+#` Match #, one or more times a digit and another #
- `)` Close caputring group
- `$` Assert the end of the string